# GTK 3 How to enter file location manually in open/save dialog permanently

Tags: gui, gtk3, ux

In GTK 3 based applications like Sublime or Firefox I have to press Ctrl+L in Open/Save dialog windows each time, to be able enter path manualy.

How do I store this settings permanenlty, to not press this keys every time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no hard and fast rule all GTK3 applications are required to follow (outside of ABI/API..). They can choose to follow the standards set by GNOME, or any other standard (even creating their own 'standard') with regards their own settings.  Thus even if you find a specific location where you can find many GTK3 programs that will comply with it, others will not (the two examples you gave tend to use their own rules, and not follow GTK standards anyway, after all they are both intended to be run equally in Qt5 environments; sublime uses its own framework over GTK3 too where possible)

Comment: @guiverc I generally agree, however this question specifically refers to GTK3 File Open/Save dialogs. Question is whether that can be configured for these for these dialogs. Of course indeed, it will then not work in programs using a GTK2 dialog or their own dialog ...

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it may not be possible to display the path bar by default. Still, there is not always a need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> first. As soon as you type `/` or `.`, the path bar will open and you can continue entering a path, helped by some autocompletion facility.

If you have an absolute path available in the clipboard, pasting that (pres <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) will open the path bar and enter the path.

Comment: Nothing seems to work for me. **CTRL+L** does nada, and the `/` or `.` just enters those characters over the filename. The only way I've found is to use the home key, and then paste a path before the filename. It's really unbelievable how much they have dumbed down GTK.

Comment: @akovia certainly not standard behaviour.

Comment: @akovia The path to the current directory is `./` so you type `./` before the filename if the file is in the current directory. Example: `./nameofafile` or `./filename` or `./foobar`